# Why is midnight added to my array instead of the date?

Tags: excel, vba

I declare a date array as such:

```
Dim date_array() as Date
```

It's goal is to store dates found in a range.

```
Dim date_range As String
```

I declare it as a string because I have an input form where a user specifies the range of dates (e.g. A1:A5).

Then I calculate how many cells are in the range and specify the size of the date_array.

```
ReDim date_array(Range(date_range).Cells.count)
```

So far so good. I then loop through each element of date_array and add the date from the range.

```
Dim i As Long
i = 0
For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name").Range(date_range)
    date_array(i) = r.Value
    i + i + 1
Next r
```

However, when I do a MsgBox(date_array(i)) during this loop, I get a value of 12:00:00 AM instead of the date I want (e.g. 2/2/2019) which tells me something is getting lost in translation.

I get the correct result if I do MsgBox(r.Value)... so it seems like something about the way I'm assigning the date to the array is wrong.

Has anyone run into an issue like this before? How can I fix it?

The larger goal is to map data between two files using date + a naming convention as a validation, so I need the array to store the correct date in a date format so it can be compared to a different cell value later.

Thank you,

Comment: try: `MsgBox FORMAT(date_array(i), "mm/dd/yyy") `

Comment: can you show some example (screenshot maybe) of the data in date_range?

Comment: `ReDim date_array(Range(date_range).Cells.count)` redims from `0` to the count, which is probably not what you want (I'd assume you want `1`, otherwise the array will have one empty element).

Comment: If I use the FORMAT, wont it convert the date to a string? I need the value to stay as a date.

Comment: date_range would return something like A2:A11 based on where the dates are.

Comment: I want the date_array to be as large as how many dates there are in my range.

Comment: this is to just check if the data has a date and not just time.  When you put the value back in the worksheet you will need to use a number format to show what you want.

Comment: MsgBox FORMAT(date_array(i), "mm/dd/yyyy") returns 12/30/1989 but MsgBox FORMAT(r.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") returns the correct date e.g. 11/1/2019 or whatever I have for the cell referenced in the range.

Comment: Try making `date_array` a `Double` and use `date_array(i) = r.Value2`

Comment: I still get the wrong date, e.g. 12/30/1989 :(

I am hesitant to use any other type than date for date_array since I need it to be in this format when making a comparison with a different cell that includes a date value at a later point.

Comment: Excel stores dates as doubles that are formatted a specific way.  But they are doubles not dates.  By storing as date the format is assumed but can have errors when translating from a different format that is not US default.